# Why a DatagramSocket does not send over the network with multicast address?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, multicast

The follow code work only locally for me. I can receive it on the same machine in another program. I can not see any traffic in the wireshark (on Windows). If I change the multicast address to an existing address like 10.10.10.10 then I see the UDP packet in wireshark.

In wireshark I use the filter udp.port == 5353. I can see some other packets to the multicast address that I thing my wireshark settings are correct.

The firewall is disabled.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    byte[] buf = "some data".getBytes();
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName( "224.0.0.251" );
    socket.send( new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length, address, 5353 ) );
}
```

EDIT: The cause seems to be a loopback adapter (Microsoft Loopbackadapter für KM-TEST). If I remove the loopback adapter then it work. On another system there is a VMware adapter which can produce an equals problem.

Why is the packet not send to all network adapters? How can I send it to the right adapter?

Comment: What are you network settings? What's the netmask?

Comment: @BoristheSpider See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending unicast datagrams, the routing tables dictate which network interface is used to send the packet.  For multicast, you need to specify the interface.  You can do that with a `MulticastSocket`.

Assuming that the IP of the interface you want to send on is 10.10.10.1, you would do the following:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    byte[] buf = "some data".getBytes();
    MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket();
    socket.setNetworkInterface(NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(
                                 InetAddress.getByName( "10.10.10.1" )));
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName( "224.0.0.251" );
    socket.send( new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length, address, 5353) );
}
```

Comment: You only need to specify the interface if it isn't the default route to the multicast address range.

Comment: @EJP For a multicast there is normally no default route.

Comment: @dbush Thanks, I send it it to every valid network interface now and it work.

Comment: I'm still confused by the fact that _binding_ the socket to the address of the needed interface does not help. You have to use `setNetworkInterface` or `setInterface` to choose the interface through which multicast datagrams will be sent.

Answer (score 1):

224.0.0/24 is [reserved](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5771#page-4):

> Local Network Control Block (224.0.0/24)

> Addresses in the Local Network Control Block are used for protocol
> control traffic that is not forwarded off link.

You can't use it.

Comment: Yes, this is the range for multicast addresses.

Comment: @Horcrux7 No, this the the range for the Local Network Control Block *sub*-range of multicast addresses.

Answer (score 1):

@EJP is correct.  You cannot use that address as a multicast address.

> The range of addresses between 224.0.0.0 and 224.0.0.255, inclusive,
>   is reserved for the use of routing protocols and other low-level
>   topology discovery or maintenance protocols, such as gateway discovery
>   and group membership reporting.  **Multicast routers should not forward
>   any multicast datagram with destination addresses in this range,
>   regardless of its TTL.**

Source: IANA - [IPv4 Multicast Address Space Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml)

In other words, your chosen multicast address *should not* work, even though it is in the range of multicast addresses.

Comment: It is the address of multicast DNS. But this is a another topic and is not related to the problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS

Comment: @Horcrux7 You cannot cite Wikipedia against an RFC. And [Wikipedia is not a reliable resource](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_is_not_a_reliable_source). If you're trying to use mDNS you need to figure out a way of setting the MAC address, which you can't do in Java.

Comment: @EJP what you means with setting of MAC address? It is working now.

Comment: @EJP You like more a RFC as Wikipedia then look here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6762